# Generate QR Code with image inside

Tags: graphics, xetex, pstricks, qrcode

How can I generate in `xelatex` a QR code with any given image inside, like [so](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/qrcode?lang=en) or better like [this](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/imageshttps://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3eT23OPqfy_SU8x7Pk7pa_b-XlPt62M4-85eTgI_ARbpVZYcDphlslDc), using either `pstricks` or the new [qrcode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/qrcode?lang=en) package? Note that the QR-code must still work after including the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follows a proposal using tikz. For the code to properly compile, the image to embed (named "image.jpg" in this code) must be present, like this one:

[image: image to embed]

The result is given by:

[image: QR code with and embedded image]

The code to produce this result is the following:

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage[forget]{qrcode}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Program to draw a QR code and insert an image in
% its center without disrupting the contents
% v.santos, 2020

\begin{document}

% Fraction of QR code width to replace
% Maximal value depends on the level of robustness of QR code
\def\wFrac{0.33}%   % 0.3 is usually OK for M (sometimes can go up to 0.4 for H)

% Dimension registers to use later
\newdimen\qrWidth
\newdimen\imWidth

% The actual desired size of the QR code in the page (should not affect the result)
\setlength{\qrWidth}{4cm}%

% define the text to embed (can change the level
% of robustness with option "level")
% The qrcode package requires some chars to be escaped (like space)
\newcommand{\myQR}{
\qrcode[height=\qrWidth,level=M]{
My\ QR\ code\ with\ an\ image\ in\ it.
 }
}%

\fbox{% % to put a frame around the QR code
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) (QR) {\myQR};
\pgfmathsetlength{\imWidth}{\wFrac*\qrWidth}
\begin{scope}[x={(QR.south east)},y={(QR.north west)}]
    \node [inner sep=0,anchor=south west] at (0.5-\wFrac/2,0.5-\wFrac/2) {\includegraphics[width=\imWidth,height=\imWidth]{image.jpg}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```